# Поиск строки содержащей целевое слово с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Знаю, что не лучшее решение, но есть ограничения на реализацию. Нужно с помощью регулярного выражения поймать тег, где содержится целевое слово. Слово может находится в любом месте. Пример, где ищем:

```
<row>
<row1> любые значения</row1>
<rowm> любые значения</rowm>
</row>
<row>
<row1> любые значения</row1>
<rown>target</rown>
<rowm> любые значения</rowm>
</row>
<row>
<row1> любые значения</row1>
<rowm> любые значения</rowm>
</row>
```

Поймать нужно :

```
<row>
<row1> любые значения</row1>
<rown>target</rown>
<rowm> любые значения</rowm>
</row>
```

В любом случаи должен использоваться глобальный модификатор s

Comment: Это xml - воспользуйтесь парсером. регулярки - не лучшее решение

Comment: Знаю, знаю, но по некоторым причинам использовать надо регулярные выражения.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, пробежался поиском по сайту. Решения здесь присутствуют, но поскольку использовать регулярки для работы с XML не лучшая идея, правильный ответ будет в каждом конкретном случае свой.
Для захвата блока с целевым словом, подойдёт такое регулярное выражение:

```
<row>(?:[^<]|<(?!\/row>))*target.*?<\/row>
```

Для захвата блока исключающего целевое слово подойдёт:

```
<row>(?:.(?!target))*?<\/row>
```